# How to remove a casperjs event listener

Tags: javascript, casperjs

I have a listener defined like this :

```
function loadFailed() {
   casper.echo("load failed catched");
}

casper.on('load.failed', loadFailed);

... some code

casper.removeListener('load.failed', loadFailed);

//redefine loadFailed function
function loadFailed(e) {
    flagLoadFailed = true;
}

b.casper.on('load.failed', loadFailed);
```

Then I have the two function working in // instead of removing the first instance by the new one.

Is there any way to remove the listener somewhere in the code (and possibly restore the original one) ?

Comment: Finally, is it even possible or not ? Thanks to tell us

Comment: Is this for a testing script?

Comment: It's for a scrapper script, no solution for the moment

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried something like:-

```
casper.on('load.failed', loadFailed)
...
casper.removeListener('load.failed', loadFailed);

function loadFailed(e) {
  ...
}
```

For a testing script you can use setup and teardown e.g.

```
casper.test.begin('Missing resources', 1, {

    setUp: function () {
        // Attach the resource listener
        casper.on('resource.received', this.onResourceReceived);
    },

    tearDown: function () {
        // Remove the resource listener
        casper.removeListener('resource.received', this.onResourceReceived);
    },

    test: function (test) {
        casper.start(...);

        casper.run(function () {
            test.done();
        });
    },

    onResourceReceived: function (resource) {
        if (resource.stage === 'end' && resource.status === 404) {
            require('utils').dump(resource);
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: I try your code (see my edit), but the first listener isn't removed (check my new comments in my own post)